# texts not displaying with ng-repeat in ion-item

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to construct a ng-repeat list with ionic-item.

I have searched on web and I am trying to do as the way like the following code, but in a ionic item. 
(Credit to author: Prashobh PS)

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/prash/Cp73s/330/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=Cp73s)

And my result is, the ion-items showing on the list and the pagination is also working. The number of items can be changed with the number of my entries on the datalist. Seems they are all working. But the problem is that the texts are not showing in the items. Only blank items are created.

Would anyone please help and give me some directions. Thank you so much!

```
<div ng-app="sampleapp">
```

```
<ul>
  <li class="paginationclass" style="font-weight:bold;"><span>Name</span><span>Age</span><span>Designation</span></li>
  <li class="paginationclass" ng-repeat="datalist in datalists | pagination: curPage * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize">
    <div><span>{{ datalist.name }} </span><span>{{ datalist.age }}</span><span>{{ datalist.designation }}</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="pagination pagination-centered" ng-show="datalists.length">
  <ul class="pagination-controle pagination">
    <li>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="curPage == 0" ng-click="curPage=curPage-1"> &lt; PREV</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Page {{curPage + 1}} of {{ numberOfPages() }}</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="curPage >= datalists.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="curPage = curPage+1">NEXT &gt;</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT： my code is like this :

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENOwvM

Comment: Please add a (part of) $scope.datalists.

Comment: Thanks JanP, may you please refer to the code I quoted for the code of datalist. I don't know why i cannot attach those code in my post. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: That's just an example I am trying to follow... when I m trying to implement them on ionic ion-item, it does seems work to create some items, but the texts in the items did not appeared.....

Comment: Try console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.datalists));

Comment: it is undefined...

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment. It should be JSON.stringify. Does that give you any result?

Comment: the result is still undefined...:(

Comment: I have checked if i do not call the data in ng-repeat but i call them out one by one then it will be fine and texts are shown. When data is called from ng-repeat, then text are not showing

Comment: Please add your controller code or make a jsfiddle...

Comment: you need to print like  {{contact.customerName}} and         {{contact.orderNumber}} to print (in your codepen)....see this http://plnkr.co/edit/XL9YcIn9ad5pSMRKwwCk?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code is different from your Codepen. Assuming the Codepen is the latest version, see this JSFiddle with a working version of your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/go9etbnv/1/

Have a look at these lines:

```
 <b>{{contact.customerName}}</b><hr>
 {{contact.orderNumber}}
```

And this part:

```
<div class="pagination pagination-centered" ng-show="datalists.contacts.length">
```

Comment: fantasic! It is working now!! Thank you so much!!! just one more question: If I would like to add a search function above the item list, using label and input attribute, should I set a ng-model="datalists.search.$" in the input tag such that it will be working?

Comment: I think best solution is ng-model on the input field to a separate variable and then use this var for filtering in your ng-repeat. But that's just a hint. Try it and if you run into any problems, raise a new question here on Stackoverflow